# Can't parse a json with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have this sort of json:

```
{
    "datas": [
        {
            "id": "001",
            "element": "#logo img",
            "category": "Test",
            "url": "http://example.com/test.html",
            "type": "file",
            "size": "10",
            "label": "Logo",
            "value": "aaaaaa"
        },
        {....
```

I try to parse it like that but it doesn't work.

```
$.get('http://example.com/datas.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        alert(data[i].type);
    })
});
```

Anyone to help me please ?

Comment: Please show us the output and tell us how you have tried to debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're accessing the data incorrectly. If that curly brace is any indication, `data` would be the entire object. You want the array inside that object.

```
$.get('http://example.com/datas.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.datas, function(i, item) {
        alert(item.type);
    })
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/vumoko/1/edit?html,js,output)</kbd>

```js
var data = {
  "datas": [
    {
      "id": "001",
      "element": "#logo img",
      "category": "Test",
      "url": "http://example.com/test.html",
      "type": "file",
      "size": "10",
      "label": "Logo",
      "value": "aaaaaa"
    }
  ]
};

$.each(data.datas, function(i, item) {
  alert(item.type);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 for(var prop in data) {
      if(data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
         console.log(data[prop]['type'];
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$.parseJSON`

https://jsfiddle.net/scheda/ehzj7qb3/

```
$.get('http://example.com/datas.json', function(data) {
    var parsed = $.parseJSON(json);
    console.log(parsed);
});
```